# How to adjust hydraulic disk brake lever reach during bleeding?

Tags: hydraulic-disc-brake, sram, ergonomics

During a crash I have bent my adjustment knob on Sram Code brakes and now after bleeding the lever is a bit too far away for my liking. The knob is bent and can't be turned. If I'll reduce the pressure in the system will it do the same as turning the knob out to make the lever closer? If so, is there any recommended procedure to **reduce** the amount of brake fluid in the system?

Comment: Sounds like your brake lever needs replacing  ?

Comment: Yep, looks like that. I'll try to bend the knob with pliers and if this doesn't work I'll check if somebody around me has a spare Sram Guide/Code brake.

Comment: Can't you just replace the lever separately and leave the piston-reservoir assembly in place, the way it is done on motorcycles?

Comment: @Carel sure you can, the levers could be bought separately. But they costs 2/3 of the brake anyway, so second hand brake as a donor is the best option in this case.

Comment: @Carel actually, my bad I might not understand your comment. You can even buy just the lever itself (the piece of aluminium), but the limiting screw is part of the top - lever reservoir assembly, so it will require replacing the whole lever with the reservoir.

Comment: @J-unior: There are levers where the screw that dials the distance from the handle bar is part of the lever. But that may well not be a feature of your item. Check for after market products maybe.

Comment: @Carell actually you are right! It is part of the lever, and costs just 13 euros. Thanks for drawing my attention!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot reduce the amount of fluid in the working part of hydraulic brakes. The reason is that hydraulic brake systems automatically draw fluid from the reservoir to compensate for brake pad wear and gradual advancement of the caliper pistons.

The way this works is when the levers are at their 'at rest' position the  reservoir is connected to the rest of the system allowing fluid to be drawn in. The first part of the travel of the piston connected to the lever cuts off the reservoir and allows the caliper pistons to be pushed out to apply the pads against the rotor. This is also why you can push the caliper pistons back in when replacing pads.